# Is it possible to use \PassOptionsToClass into a package?

Tags: document-classes, package-writing, class-options

Context: I'm building a new package for my university. I need to set a lot of options for the document class, like `twoside`, `a4paper`, `12pt`, or `firstpagenum=chapter`.

I would like to set them by default in my package without creating a new class. Is it possible?

Comment: Maybe what you actually need to develop is a class file instead of a package. They're equally easy or difficult, depending on your experience. As Grandmaster Carlisle has indicated, unless you use `\RequirePackage` on top of `\documentclass`, passing options to a class from a package will require a new invention. Passing options to class after the class file has been read is not possible - and the class file can’t be read twice. In your class file, you can call `\PassOptionsToClass` before `\LoadClass`, or, in place of these two commands, simply call \LoadClassWithOptions.

Answer (score 8):

No the class file has been read by the time you load a package, But it sounds like you should be defining a class file. you can have myclass.cls just handle the options it needs and then `\LoadClassWithOptions{article}` (or whichever base class you need).